# problems with games_howell_test in R or `df` must be size 15 or 1, not 12

Tags: r, dplyr

While running my old existing code to conduct a pairwise comparisons test in R, encountered a new problem. The data, code and error are provided below.

**Data:**

```
Genotype Tillering
Geno1   22
Geno1   23
Geno1   23
Geno1   23
Geno2   22
Geno2   22
Geno2   22
Geno2   22
Geno3   23
Geno3   22
Geno3   23
Geno3   23
Geno4   23
Geno4   23
Geno4   23
Geno4   23
Geno5   21
Geno5   21
Geno5   20
Geno5   21
Geno6   22
Geno6   22
Geno6   22
Geno6   22
```

**Code:**

```
library(openxlsx)
df <- read.xlsx("games_howel error.xlsx")
df <- df %>% mutate(Genotype = factor(Genotype))
df2 <- games_howell_test(df, Tillering~Genotype, detailed = T) %>% print (n=15)
```

**Error:**

```
> df2 <- games_howell_test(df, Tillering~Genotype, detailed = T) %>% print (n=15)

Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `data = map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `df = df$value`.
Caused by error:
! `df` must be size 15 or 1, not 12.
```

Comment: Where does `games_howell_test()` come from?

Comment: From the library(rstatix)

Comment: Maybe contact the package maintainer? https://github.com/kassambara/rstatix/issues This seems to be a bug that I can reproduce.

Comment: Done https://github.com/kassambara/rstatix/issues/183, thanks for the suggestion. Just a comment that might be useful to fix the bug: "When I change some of the phenotype (tillering) values it does work".